# Disable semi-color in EsLint

Tags: atom-editor, eslint, lint, resource-files

I've found the correct line in the .eslintrc.js file. Was not able to find anything in the EsLint documentation about disabling.

Should I change/delete error?
Should I change always to false or off?

```
"semi": [
    "error",
    "always"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring Rules
ESLint comes with a large number of rules. You can modify which rules your project uses either using configuration comments or configuration files. To change a rule setting, you must set the rule ID equal to one of these values:

"off" or 0 - turn the rule off
"warn" or 1 - turn the rule on as a warning (doesn’t affect exit code)
"error" or 2 - turn the rule on as an error (exit code is 1 when triggered)